# drawing on image of a picturebox c#

Tags: c#, drawing, picturebox

Hello i am in problem with drawing in picturebox. I am trying to draw over a picturebox. picturebox contains an image.I draw a sine wave using drawline method. when the wave reaches the end of the width of picturebox then i use

```
 g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
```

this clears the wave over the picturebox.But the problem is it also clears the image of the picturebox.I want draw a wave over a image and then clears it when it reaches the picturebox.width and again starts from the initial position. please help!

```
Graphics g;
g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Crimson, ti, old_gval1, ti + trackBar1.Value, gval1);

                usb.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(OUTBuffer);    

            old_gval1 = gval1;

            ti = ti + trackBar1.Value;
            if (ti > pictureBox1.Width) { 
                ti = 0;

                g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
                g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Gray, 0, ((pictureBox1.Height - 1) - (gnd_val) * ((pictureBox1.Height - 10) / 1023f)), pictureBox1.Width, ((pictureBox1.Height - 1) - (gnd_val) * ((pictureBox1.Height - 10) / 1023f)));
                g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Gray,  pictureBox1.Width / 2, 0,  pictureBox1.Width/ 2,pictureBox1.Height);

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special feature of the PictureBox:

It has not only the `Image` everybody is using but also a `BackgroundImage` usually overlooked.

You can paint freely on the `Image` and still keep a `BackgroundImage` untouched.

Obviosly you need to paint on a transparent Bitmap.

Here is some code:

```
// load the background image:

this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(yourImageFileName);

// prepare the image:

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
using (Graphics g  = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) )
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size) );
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Now paint stuff:

```
Random R = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image bmp = pictureBox2.Image;
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, R.Next(33), R.Next(33), R.Next(500), R.Next(500));
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, R.Next(33), R.Next(33), R.Next(500), R.Next(500));
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, R.Next(33), R.Next(33), R.Next(500), R.Next(500));
    }
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
}
```

When your plotting has reached the right edge you would use a call to `FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent,..` to clear the foreground image and reset your x value.

Sounds like the cheapest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. You could create your graphics from the image using [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx), then assign the image from that to the picture box.
2. Draw the image into your new `Graphics` object using [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx).

It sounds like the latter might be a bit more appropriate for you, since you aren't actually altering the in-memory image. So every time you clear the `Graphics` instance, just draw in the `Image`.